# IF NOT EXISTS statement not working correctly after 1st execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I am trying to insert data into a table *feed.author* from another table *feed.tempXML*. The First time I execute this statement it works perfectly fine, but when i add data in *feed.tempXML* and run it again the new authors are not being added into the *feed.author* table. Does the IF statement need to change ?

Code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT  DISTINCT t.author FROM feed.tempXML t 
    JOIN feed.author a ON a.author = t.author)
        INSERT INTO feed.author(author)
        SELECT  DISTINCT author
        FROM feed.tempXML
        WHERE author  IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Do INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ...

Comment: @jarlh Same outcome :/

Comment: You have to remove IF NOT EXISTS first...

Comment: Your query basically says: "if anything from feed.tempXML exists in feed.author - insert nothing". You need to change to `WHERE NOT EXISTS` as explained

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem in your query is, In `IF` condition you checking for the record existence but while inserting you are not doing it.

It should be done like this

```
INSERT INTO feed.author
            (author)
SELECT DISTINCT author
FROM   feed.tempXML t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   feed.author a
                   WHERE  a.author = t.author)
       AND t.author IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right, why not to use `EXCEPT`?

```
INSERT INTO feed.author (author)
SELECT author
FROM feed.tempXML
WHERE author IS NOT NULL
EXCEPT
SELECT author
FROM feed.author;
```

This will insert users from `feed.tempXML` that do not yet exist in `feed.author`

Also, if remember that 'author' from 'feed.tempXML' table can have empty strings (in a theory, maybe in your case not) so it is wise to replace `IS NOT NULL` with `> ''`. So the query becomes:

```
INSERT INTO feed.author (author)
SELECT author
FROM feed.tempXML
WHERE author > ''
EXCEPT
SELECT author
FROM feed.author;
```